# JS: How to get two IDs

Tags: javascript

This won’t work:

```
<a onclick="if(document.getElementById('div2','div1') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('div2','div1') .style.display=''}else
{document.getElementById('div2','div1') .style.display='none'}">
this1 ~~
</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none"> 
1
</div>

<a onclick="if(document.getElementById('div2') .style.display=='none') {document.getElementById('div2') .style.display=''}else
{document.getElementById('div2') .style.display='none'}">
this2 ~~
</a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none"> 
2
</div>
```

How do I show div2 and div1 when I click on this1~~? It only shows div2 on click instead of showing both. Why isn’t it working?

Comment: `getElementById` only takes one parameter.  You'd need to call it twice.  P.S. Don't actually use `onclick`.  You should use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener).

Comment: can you show me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript has no place in HTML tags.  It should stay on its own.  That being said, `getElementById` only gets one element.  You'd need to call it twice to get two elements.

Try something like this:

```
<a id="this1">this1 ~~</a>
<div id="div1" style="display:none">1</div>

<a id="this2">this2 ~~</a>
<div id="div2" style="display:none">2</div>
```

Then in your `<head>`, add the JavaScript:

```
// Make sure the page is ready
window.onload = function(){
    // Save references to them, so we don't need to keep looking them up
    var div1 = document.getElementById('div1'),
        div2 = document.getElementById('div2');

    // Add events to our <a> tags
    document.getElementById('this1').addEventListener('click', function(){
        // Toggle div1 and div2
        if(div1.style.display === 'none' && div2.style.display === 'none'){
            div1.style.display = div2.style.display = '';
        }
        else{
            div1.style.display = div2.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('this2').addEventListener('click', function(){
        // Toggle div2 only
        if(div2.style.display === 'none'){
            div2.style.display = '';
        }
        else{
            div2.style.display = 'none';
        }
    });
};
```